# Zipkin is not nesting parent trace to its child

Tags: twitter, cassandra, trace, zipkin

We are using finagle stack and taught of adding zipkin for tracing our micro-services.

I am able to see our tracing happening but parent finishes before the child.

I have already opened an issue here: 
https://github.com/openzipkin/docker-zipkin/issues/100

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was recording wrong annotation i.e client instead of server.

Just a simple change did the trick.

`Trace.traceService("Function1","Test")`

Sample working Zipkin example: https://gist.github.com/AkhilJ876/3e38757c28d43924f296dd2d147c0bd9#file-zipkintracing_example-L34